# How can I avoid putting my e-mail password in plain text in my `.fetchmailrc` file?

Tags: email, passwords, encryption, fetchmail

How can I avoid putting my e-mail password in plain text in my `.fetchmailrc` file? My file looks like this:

```
poll pop.XXX.com with proto POP3
user 'abc' with password 'PASSWORD' there is foobar here 
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T" 
options
no keep
ssl
```

I learned this from http://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html but it saves my password in plain text, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Store the `.fetchmailrc` in an encrypted filesystem (possibly `ecryptfs` or `encfs`) and symlink it to `~/`.

---

If you don't want to move the entire `fetchmailrc` file, you can create a `~/.netrc` with the password:

```
machine pop.XXX.com
    login abc
    password "Password"
```